# Using a for loop to find the location of all strings in a list (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

I am currently trying to create a list of string locations from a list of strings. I tried to search this, but most of the tutorials only seemed to cover printing using for loops.

```
message = "Example string."
L = ['m', 'p', 'l']
for P in range(len(L)):
    message.find(L)
```

This is a mockup code that doesn't work, but this is an example of the string:

**INPUT :**

```
message = "Example string."
L = ['m', 'p', 'l']
```

I want to define a new list that will return

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> L = ['m', 'p', 'l']
>>> lst=[]
>>> for i in L:
        lst.append(message.index(i))

>>> lst
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Good to hear :-) please mark the answer as useful and mark it as answer

Comment: you might as well use a list comp: `[message.index(c) for c in 'mpl']`

Comment: @SandeepLade : its better to use `find`, as `index` can throw up an `Error` if the char is not found.

Comment: @KaushikNP : Yes i agree find is better solution

Answer (score 3):

Using simple `list comprehension` :

```
>>> out = [ message.find(s) for s in L]
>>> out
=> [3, 4, 5]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : message = "Example string."
IN : L = ['m', 'p', 'l']
```

Answer (score 1):

a list comp is a better solution to this:

```
[message.index(c) for c in L]
```